# Is it really OK to use "because of"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I recently learned from a YouTube video that "because of" is not correct. But my friend argues that "because of" *is* actually correct. Also, I see a lot of people writing and saying "because of". Here's a example:

> That's **because of** you.

***So, is it actually correct to use "because of" or only new learners think it's correct or is it not correct at all?***

Comment: This is a great example of why learning things from random YouTube videos is not the best idea.

Comment: (Can you provide a link to the video? I'm interested in the source/authority because of its broad use colloquially).

Comment: I'm curious too as the name of the video. But I wouldn't be surprised if the OP had misinterpreted or oversimplified the lesson/rule/guide

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Actually, '*of*' can be correct, in standard grammar, after *because*. It depends on what comes after that.

If the next part is a complete and potentially free-standing clause (say, a verb phrase), then you don't need (or want) *of*:

> That's because I'm smart.
>   I'm hungry because I haven't eaten.
>   You're only saying that because I'm pretty.
>   I'm wet because it's raining.

But if the bit after it is a noun phrase, you need the *of*:

> That's because of my asthma.
>   I'm angry because of your tone.
>   I'm happy because of you.
>   You're only saying that because of my looks.

You will also run into a lot of non-standard usage in some places using the *of* even where it isn't used in standard grammar.

Answer (score 24):

Both *because* and *because of* are correct **in different contexts**.

- *Because* is used by itself when the cause is expressed as a clause:

  > He opened his umbrella **because it was raining**.
- *Because* is used with *of* when the cause is expressed as a noun or nominal:

  > He opened his umbrella **because of the rain**.

  However, there is a fairly new hip usage which drops *of*; often it also drops determiners on the nominal representing the cause, casting the cause as a 'generic':

  > He opened his umbrella because rain.

  This usage is quite widespread, but not yet ready for formal registers. In her admirable article ["English Has a New Preposition, Because Internet"](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/11/english-has-a-new-preposition-because-internet/281601/) Megan Garber describes it as "exceptionally bloggy and aggressively casual and implicitly ironic".

Comment: I wouldn't call that so much a new usage as a bit of deliberately and creatively non-standard grammar. The fact it's 'wrong' is part of its charm.

Comment: @SamBC That's where new usages come from. 600 years ago most of what traditionalists call subordinating conjunctions (including bare *because* with a content clause) were similar truncations of *because/for/when/before/etc **that*** [clause].

Comment: Ach laddie, ye kenna know yer heathens. :)

Comment: I observe the "new hip" usage almost only in the phrase "... because reasons", which is usually somewhat humoristic or mocking someone who actually does not state a reason

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I've seen it in lots of contexts; check out Garber's article at the link for some more.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's the main construction with which the usage began; it has definitely expanded beyond that by now, because internet.

Comment: The third usage ("because ___________") is short for "because of things implied by the concept labelled ___________".

Comment: @Jasper You can paraphrase conventional *because of* in exactly the same way. A long paraphrase does not imply that a short form is elliptical.

Comment: @StoneyB -- But traditional "because of" is not used with expressions like "internet" or "Science" or "(R-Oklahoma)".  Whereas the newfangled "because" is.

Comment: @Jasper. Ah, now that's a point I hadn't noticed: the new form also drops determiners. Thanks! I'll incorporate that.